# User account always pop Invalid activation link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

activation link is not work
I try to delete `user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])`
Account is activated
I don't know where have problem.

user.rb

```
def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
end
```

account_activations_controller.rb

```
  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email]) 

    if user && !user.activated?&& user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
        log_in user
        flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

user_controller.rb

```
def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
        flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
          render 'new'
      end
  end
```

account_activation.html.erb:

```
<h1>Sample_app</h1>

<p>
  <%= @greeting %><%= @user.name %>
</p>
<p>
Welcome to the sample_app! Click on the link below to activate your account:
</p>
<%= link_to "Activate!", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

user_mailer.rb:

```
  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: @user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end
```

My terminal:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q90tt.jpg)

and I use `params.insect`
it show :
{"email"=>"3Dadmin@example.com", "controller"=>"account_activations", "action"=>"edit", "id"=>"rPf9SJNob23cBpzomQ7O=eg"}

''3D'' is add in front of the email

admin@example.com   <--current

3Dadmin@example.com <--error

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to give us a bit more information for us to help you. The code you have shown doesn't seem to have anything wrong. Can you please *edit your question* and add more code there. Please add the form that you are using. Please add any error message you get. Can you check what is in the `params` before the first line of `def edit` ? eg add `puts params.inspect` as the first line.

Comment: If I create a new user , it will send this "http://localhost:3000/account_activations/7NG0m3JprYmaElG3Knsn=
SA/edit?email=3Dadmin%40example.com" by email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be sending an *edit* link for your activations. To activate a user... you want something else.

I'd be guessing something like:

```
<%= link_to "Activate!", account_activation_url(@user.activation_token) %>
```

I could be wrong on the exact link you need, but I know for sure that the edit link is wrong... so read the docs on what you should be doing instead.